# What is purpose of the "assignments" in the Qsys custom component editor signals and interfaces tab?

Tags: quartus

Here is the image showing what I am talking about,
[image]
For Avalon Memory Mapped Slave port I can see that there are 4 options already there and they are already assigned custom values.

I just want to know, what is the usage of this "assignments" when making custom components and what is the usage of the assignments that are already defined and set for the Avalon Memory Mapped Slave port? i.e what is the master supposed to do if any of these options isFlast, isMemoryDevice isNonVolatileStorage, isPrintableDevice where '1' rather than '0'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, that's just a different way of seeing (and setting) all of the options for the IP that are also settable in the tabs and fields of the main window, summarizing them all in one place. It corresponds more closely to what you see if you look at the generated code.